# Reducing bandwidth for testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, proxy, bandwidth, load-testing

For testing purposes etc. I need
1) Ways to reduce bandwidth on a connection (each direction)
2) Simulate broken connection.
3) Measure bandwidth, perhaps see whats going through.

I am thinking of something like a proxy or perhaps something plugging into Apache/Tomcat

(Should look like a http URL/URI to the client)

Comment: www.fiddler2.com can do most of that.

Comment: I can't see much of bandwidth limitation.  th

Comment: I am using iprelay/fiddler.  Though I would like accumulated traffic, and it seems I can for example just export to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "proxy" can simulate all of that for you and does a good job as well.. http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Commercial tools can be very expensive for this kind of testing so worth the effort setting up a dedicated linux box for this. I have not tried the windows version yet..

Comment: ipreleay seems about the same, and simpler, more easy to get?

Answer (score 1):

Found this one for Windows using Fiddler
http://www.logic-worx.com/index.php/tools-and-apps/fiddler-connection-simulator/